# Border color IE vs Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, border

On my site [cryptscript](http://cryptscript.com)

the border color is darker in ie than in Firefox and I can't seem to fix it?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much. They are the same color. The fact that it is running in VMWare is probably the cause of it *appearing* to look different.

Comment: Even if the colors in vmware where not the same as not in vmware it would not matter because i am running firefox and ie side by side in the vmware so if the colors where off they would be off by the same amount and look the same to me but they don't?

Comment: Please see my answer, I added the explanation on what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks the same to me. Are you looking at them on different monitors?

EDIT:

I see now. You are using a "ridge" border style. It is a known fact that it renders differently in different browsers. Mentioned [here](http://htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/border-style/). If you want a consistent look for the border, use the simple styles. Your other choice is to create custom borders by way of background images. [Here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customcorners/) is a starting point to explain the concept.

Comment: Nope I am using firefox 3.6.8 and ie 8 on windows xp in vmware and they are different?

Comment: here is a zoomed in image of the borders http://img299.imageshack.us/img299/8328/color2z.jpg they are not the same.